# Pandas pivot table from CSV with checkmarks

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a CSV file which looks something like this

| data_source | destination | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | A description |
| B | 2 | B description |
| C | 3 | C description |
| A | 3 | A description |

and I'm looking to generate a pivot table that looks something like this

| description | data_source | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A description | A | x |  | x |
| B description | B |  | x |  |
| C description | C |  |  | x |

The closest I've gotten so far is this

```
table = pd.pivot_table(df, index='data_source', columns='destination', values=['data_source'], aggfunc='first')
```

I tried using ['description', 'data_source'] as the index to get the description and data_source rows but  I end up with a 0 column table. I also don't know the data type for what gets passed to aggfunc to output an 'x' in the valued cells.

I'm new to Pandas and I don't have a good mental model yet so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for`pd.crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab([df['data_source'],df['description']], df['destination']).reset_index()
Out[101]: 
destination data_source   description  1  2  3
0                     A  Adescription  1  0  1
1                     B  Bdescription  0  1  0
2                     C  Cdescription  0  0  1
```